# Wordpress redirect to parent of first child

Tags: wordpress, parent-child

I would like when a user clicks on some parent in Wordpress theme, that it finds first subparent with children and redirects to it.

I have found similar solution, but it redirects me to first child of a parent, which is not good.

```
if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
        if ($pagekids) {
            if (!get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dont_redirect', true)) {
                $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
                wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I need a parent of this child above.

A tried various things, but constantly fall in an endless loop.

If i click (on the left navigation) on IZDELKI it redirects me to LANTERNA ODPRTA. It needs to be redirected to STROPNE LUČI

This is the structure:
http://supernet.si/client/drugacno/Untitled-1.jpg

Comment: you checks only `child_of`.

Comment: if you want to check the result of `$pagekids`, than make it! You get only the **first** parent with `child_of`.

Comment: Hm,.. here is my working site: http://supernet.si/client/drugacno/izdelki/

Comment: If i click (on the left navigation) on IZDELKI it redirects me to 
LANTERNA ODPRTA. It needs to be redirected to STROPNE LUČI.

Comment: cant find that. IZDELKI is on the top navigation and here are only submenus

Comment: I was working on with a project and used Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin, by which you can manually rewrite/redefine each post's url, redirect it. Downside is, it is not automatical if new pages, parents are added. Redirects have to be manually defined through WP CMS.

Comment: I added screenshot of structure if you are still interested: http://supernet.si/client/drugacno/Untitled-1.jpg 

Nobody solved this until now. All solutions are redirections to a child page and not to a child's page parent.